# Python formatting when `format()` dot notation involved

Tags: python, code-formatting, pep8

I'm new to Python, looking for how to format the code below per PEP8 standards:

- Using Python 3.5 so `fstrings` are not available.
- With all the `.format()`, its tough to know where to split the line.

**Unformatted:**

```
hist_df = spark.read.format("delta").table("{table}".format(table=selected_table))
hist_query = hist_df.where(col("status")=='{sel_status}'.format(sel_status=selected_status)).where(col("cret_dt") < '{last_date}'.format(last_date=selected_last_date)).drop("cret_ts", "cret_dt")


file_path = "abfss://{cont}@{acct}.dfs.core.windows.net/{folder}/".format(cont=storage_container, acct=storage_account, folder=selected_folder)
```

**Here is what I want to do (which executes fine):**

- To me, this lines up the `hist_query` filter parameters nicely
- Also lines up the `file_path` `format()` parameters nicely

```
hist_df = spark.read.format("delta").table("{table}".format(table=selected_table))
hist_query = (hist_df.
             where(col("status")=='{sel_status}'.format(sel_status=selected_status)).
             where(col("cret_dt") < '{last_date}'.format(last_date=selected_last_date)).
             drop("cret_ts", "cret_dt"))


file_path = ("abfss://{cont}@{acct}.dfs.core.windows.net/{folder}/".
             format(
               cont=storage_container, 
               acct=storage_account, 
               folder=sel_folder
             ))
```

But is this format in line with Python PEP8 standards? It feels counterintuitive to have the `.` dangling off the end of some lines.

Comment: If you are new to Python, why are you using Python 3.5? It's seriously outdated.

Comment: [Databricks 5.5LTS is "stuck" on 3.5](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html#will-my-existing-pypi-libraries-work-with-python-3). I'm unwilling to rally and pass an Act of Enterprise Congress to update the cluster :). What are your thoughts on the code format?

Comment: @Nat Riddle it's not 1 year old , it's almost 6 years old !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PEP 8 - The official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), your code seems nicely formatted. Keep in mind though, that some things are a matter of preference. Adopting all of the suggestions is less important than being consistent about it in your code. You can use a [code formatter](https://deepsource.io/blog/python-code-formatters/) to help you with that. Different code formatter have different default settings. For example, your code formated by Black would end up like this:

```
hist_df = spark.read.format("delta").table("{table}".format(table=selected_table))
hist_query = (
    hist_df.where(col("status") == "{sel_status}".format(sel_status=selected_status))
    .where(col("cret_dt") < "{last_date}".format(last_date=selected_last_date))
    .drop("cret_ts", "cret_dt")
)


file_path = "abfss://{cont}@{acct}.dfs.core.windows.net/{folder}/".format(
    cont=storage_container, acct=storage_account, folder=selected_folder
)
```

That's because in Black the default maximum characters per line setting is 88 while for PEP 8 is 79.

Comment: Thanks for the resources and sanity check. I will pull the code over to VS Code (being written in Databricks Notebook) and see how it formats too. As much as I don't like the dangling `.`, I do like the parameter alignment.